# Run a shell script from terminal with string and python list argument

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script that calls a function from a python file that I created. That function needs two arguments, one string and one list of strings. I am trynig to figure out how can i call that script form the console. My scirpt is:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 cd $1
 python -c "from my_file import my_function; my_function( \"$2\" )"
```

The first argument is the path of `my_file.py` while the second one is a python list of strings. How can I call the script from the terminal?

My script is working if I call it from a python file like (and have input two strings for example):

```
arguments = ["./script.sh", path, args1]
ret_val = subprocess.Popen(arguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can pass it as command line argument to python.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $1
python -c "from my_file import my_function; import sys; my_function(sys.argv[1])" $2
```

Comment: My script is working when I call it from a python file like the posted example.

Comment: Ok, you can just call it with `./script path arg1_text`?